# implement a queue

Tags: c++, queue

I have the following queue class (taken from wordpress):

```
#include<iostream.h>

class Queue
    {
    private:
     int data;
     Queue*next;
    public:
     void Enque(int);
     int Deque();
    }*head,*tail;    

    void Queue::enque(int data)
    {
     Queue *temp;
    temp=new Queue;
    temp->data=data;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(heads==NULL)
     heads=temp;
    else
    tail->next=temp;
    tail=temp;
    }

    int Queue::deque()
    {
    Queue* temp;//
    temp=heads;
    heads=heads->next;
    return temp->data;
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out why the compiler tells me that I have a multiple definition
of "head" and "tail"- without success.

edit: When the compiler gives the error message it opens up a locale_facets.tcc file
 from I-don't-know-where and says that the error is on line 2497 in  the following function:

```
bool
 __verify_grouping(const char* __grouping, size_t __grouping_size,
        const string& __grouping_tmp)
```

Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: Lol- I wish this was my homework. My homework is a huge assignment building a graph with dynamic storage. I need this queue to help me implement a BFS search on it...
But point taken.

Comment: @Meir - any reason you can't use the std queue and must implement it by yourself? Sounds kind of weird, queue is a very basic and common standard lib.

Comment: Can you post the entire queue class?

Comment: That is not a Queue class, that is one function fromt eh queue class... In fact there is no variable "head" and there is no declaration of "tail", so it's sort of hard to help you out. Also, why are you using this queue implementation... you should read all the posts to your other question where you asked about using a queue.

Comment: Please explain why you can't use std queue, but why you are allowed to rip one off from wordpress.

Comment: Whoops. I've now added the deceleration of the class. @Tom- even though I realise that C++ includes a built in queue I'd like to get this one to work.

Comment: You really ought to fix the spacing, and what is the compiler error? Copy and past it... indicate in comments the line numbers it refers to.

Comment: @Yuval: It is weird. I'm going to talk to the TA responsible for the exercise tomorrow. Till then- G.night and thanks for your help!

Comment: Tom, it isn't ripped off from Wordpress, it is being ripped off from a blog hosted by Wordpress. I agree with your sentiment though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this is homework, here is some information about queues and how you could go about implementing one.

A Queue is a standard Abstract Data Type.
It has several properties associated with it:

1. It is a linear data structure - all components are arranged in a straight line.
2. It has a grow/decay rule - queues add and remove from opposite ends.
3. Knowledge of how they're constructed shouldn't be integral in using them because they have public interfaces available.

Queues can be modeled using Sequential Arrays or Linked-Lists.
If you're using an array there are some things to consider because you grow in one direction so you will eventually run out of array. You then have some choices to make (shift versus grow). If you choose to shift back to the beginning of the array (wrap around) you have to make sure the head and tail don't overlap. If you choose to simply grow the queue, you have a lot of wasted memory.

If you're using a Linked-List, you can insert anywhere and the queue will grow from the tail and shrink from the head. You also don't have to worry about filling up your list and having to wrap/shift elements or grow.

However you decide to implement the queue, remember that Queues should provide some common interface to use the queue. Here are some examples:

1. enqueue - Inserts an element at the back (tail) of the queue
2. dequeue - Remove an element from the front (head) of a non-empty queue.
3. empty - Returns whether the queue is empty or not
4. size - Returns the size of the queue

There are other operations you might want to add to your queue (In C++, you may want an iterator to the front/back of your queue) but how you build your queue should not make a difference with regards to the operations it provides.

However, depending on how you want to use your queue, there are better ways to build it. The usual tradeoff is insert/removal time versus search time. Here is [a decent reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_lists_vs._arrays).

Answer (score 5):

If your assignment is not directly related to queue implementation, you might want to use the built in `std::queue` class in C++:

```
#include <queue>

void test() {
    std::queue<int> myQueue;
    myQueue.push(10);
    if (myQueue.size())
        myQueue.pop(); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just use the queue in standard C++ library?

```
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    queue<int> Q;

    Q.push(1);
    Q.push(2);
    Q.push(3);

    Q.top(); // 1
    Q.top(); // 1 again, we need to pop
    Q.pop(); // void

    Q.top(); // 2
    Q.pop();

    Q.top(); // 3
    Q.pop();

    Q.empty(); // true
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write top instead of pop? Thanks for the answer, the most straight forward one I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things wrong:

- Your methods are declared as Enqueue and Dequeue, but defined as enqueue and dequeue: C++ is case sensitive.
- Your methods refer to "heads" which doesn't appear to exist, do you mean "head"?

Comment: I assume you are not leaving this as a comment because you cannot comment... therefore I am only giving you +1 so that you can get closer to commenting since it was a good comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this for BFS... just use deque.

```
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

void BFS() {
    deque<GraphNode*> to_visit;
    to_visit.push_back(start_node);
    while (!to_visit.empty()) {
        GraphNode* current = to_visit.front();
        current->visit(&to_visit);  // enqueues more nodes to visit with push_back
        to_visit.pop_front();
    }
}
```

The `GraphNode::visit` method should do all your "work" and add more nodes to the queue to visit. the only methods you should need are `push_back()`, `front()`, and `pop_front()`

This is how I always do it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem *might* have something to do with the fact that:

```
class Queue {
  // blah
} *head, * tail;
```

is defining a `Queue` class, and declaring `head` and `tail` as type `Queue*`. They do not look like members of the class, which they should be.